# How is bisector of one side of a right angled triangle, drawn from right angled corner equal to the half of the bisected side?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In a right angled triangle ABC with right angle at B and D being the mid-point of side AC, is it possible to prove BD=AD=CD without using co-ordinate geometry or circle theorems etc? (Just by using other elementary theorems: This has bothered me since my school years)

Comment: Thales' theorem: any right triangle can be inscribed in a semi-circle with the diameter coincident with the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** Complete the triangle to a rectangle in the obvious way. (Make a copy of the triangle, and rotate it into place.)

Comment: Does it require to BDB' fall in same line?

Comment: GOT it by ASA.. Cool

Comment: Good. After one draws the rectangle, a bit of angle-chasing finishes things.